# C# how to add object to a list which has list of object

Tags: c#, algorithm

let me try to explain this
I have two lists 
1. list of employee objects
2.list of department objects(which has list of employee who can work in the department)

I want to be able to add a employee to a department in the list which has list of employees.

but I am getting null error

```
int empsize = allemployees.Count;
        int Maxdepartment = 0;



        foreach (employee employeeitem in allemployees)
        {

            Maxdepartment = employeeitem.alloweddepartments.Count;


            for (int i = 0; i < Maxdepartment; i++)
            {
                int index = alldepartments.FindIndex(x => x.Name == employeeitem.alloweddepartments[i].ToString());

                alldepartments[index].earlyshift.Add(employeeitem);








            }
```

Comment: Would be better if we see your work..

Comment: show us your (inefficient?) solution and maybe one of us knows a better one

Comment: The employees say when they want to start and end for each day (e.g. MondayIn, MondayOut)? and you want to calculate the perfect day off in respect of all employees and assign them to differend departments? why you use float instead of DateTime?

Comment: yes but the twist is each department has a min and max staff requirement to prevent over and under staffing(see department class ).

Comment: does every department has a "need of hours per day" which varies per day? e.g. hours on sunday < hours on monday, department a needs 30 workhours a day, department b needs 100 workhours per day? show us the departmentclass (unless its not only a string with its name) are the prefered times of the employees a "must" or can they get changed if it make sence for the assignments? have you even thought about the parameters you need here?

Comment: sorry about the float i need to fix that its was because my MySQL didn't want to work with data and time. i will fix that

Comment: class departments
{
    public int Did { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Minemployee { get; set; }
    public int Maxemployee { get; set; }
    public float earlyshift { get; set; }
    public float lateshift { get; set; }
    public float earlyshiftend { get; set; }
    public float lateshiftend { get; set; }

    public departments(string name){


        Name = name;

}

Comment: Your could should be subjected to some code review. Having 14 variables for [day][in/out] is not the best looking solution I've seen... But since that's out of scope for this site you'd have to post a code review to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a very complex problem for me. Its for sure a optimization problem with many constraints, so i hope you are good at math ;-).

I would suggest to have a look at the [Simplex Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) which will work very well for your problem if you have the mathematical know how to use it. There are some variations of the simplex too which maybe also work well.

There is an other way too where you just use the power of your computer to solve the problem. You could write a function which rates a solution and gives you some kind of benchmarkscore.
For instance you can rate the hour difference of provided and needed like every hour which is smaller then the needed is a -2, every hour which is bigger then needed is -1. So you can get a score to an employee assignment.

with this function you can start to randomly assign employees to departments (of course accourding to the min/max employees for each department) and then rate this solution using your function. so you can find a solution with a good score (if your defined function works well)

most of random assignments will be stupid of course but your computer generates million of solutions in seconds so chances are good that it will generate a good one after some time (dont think time is a big critera here cause once you have a solution it wont change very often)